# New Zealand SMC Job Search Visa to Residence Visa

Tags: visa, immigration, new-zealand, skilled-migration

My wife is the main applicant, and we applied for SMC residence Visa for a family last year in September 2018. Yesterday got email stated offer Job Search Visa for my wife. I am very confused and upset because my children are very young if my wife will go alone we will face many problems. Now I have some question please guide me and suggest me as follows:

1. We applied for SMC residence visa. Why they offer Job Search Visa?
2. If my wife will not get the same job as we mentioned in SMC application, and she gets any other job in a different field (not skilled) and secures a job offer, will this work to obtain a residence visa and to satisfy CO?
3. If we request an email to CO for the visa of the whole family instead of Main Applicant, is it possible CO allow us to travel with the Main applicant to NZ?
4. What is the time frame for converting JSV to RV?

Please suggest the possible way and guide us on what to do?
Please share any other aspects and points what is not in my mind now?

Thanks

Edit: my wife got 175 points in EOI. She does not have a NZ job offer.

Comment: Was no reason given in the email? Did your wife meet or exceed the points cut-off (currently 160) for an SMC visa? https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/visa-factsheet/skilled-migrant-category-resident-visa Did she have a job offer? https://www.enz.org/forum/showthread.php?t=55464

Comment: Yes she got 175 points in EOI.

Comment: No job offer from NZ

Answer (score 0):

Q1 You say that your wife does not have a job offer from NZ. Applicants who are not eligible for a resident visa because they do not have skilled employment or the required qualification, but meet all other Skilled Migrant Category requirements, may be eligible for an SMC Job Search work visa. The purpose of the SMC Job Search work visa is to allow the applicant the opportunity to obtain skilled employment in New Zealand.

Q2  A 12 month work visa may be granted if the applicant is  outside New Zealand. A residence application will be deferred for the length of the work visa granted. If you receive an offer of skilled employment or begin working in a skilled job during the course of your work visa, INZ will assess your employment and make a decision on your residence application. If your work visa expires and you have not obtained a skilled job or job offer, your residence application will be declined.

Q3 Family members are not automatically eligible for any temporary entry visas that are linked to your SMC Job Search work visa. If any family members wish to accompany the applicant, they must apply and meet standard temporary entry class visa instructions.

Q4 See 2 above

Source: https://www.immigration.govt.nz/documents/forms-and-guides/inz1105.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

There are some ambiguities after your email please confirm and explain

------    1. My question is that if they don’t willing to give RV visa why they don’t inform at the beginning of the process or not mentioned on the website? I am asking this because I have applied with family for a residence visa for a family well being and live together in NZ as we are living in a home country. Thus, INZ wastes our time and money in this process such as medical, fees, travel documents, and IELTS fees, etc.

Comment: 2. For instance, my wife will go to NZ Alone and she will find some common job bellow mentioned:
1. Warehouse job, Inventory Controller or 
2. Packer / Picker and Restaurant Helper
3. Other jobs Like I have seen on Trade Me and Seek are most common and salary around 19 NZ dollar.
4. I have seen in every job advertisement this Line: Applicants for this position should have NZ residency or a valid NZ work visa. (How my wife can get these job).

Comment: Any job whether Any job at ANZSCO list or Short Term Skill Shortage or Long Term Skill Shortage / Immediate Skill shortage at any salary slab and how much working hours in a week can help to obtain residence visa satisfy CO.

Comment: 3. What are the chances of getting a visit visa for my family because me and children’s apply separately we will face many problems like:
1. Funds showing in my wife bank account for JSV, how we arrange and maintain for my bank account to meet visit visa requirement obviously borrow money from someone and can maintain 6 months bank statement?
2. Fees of my and children’s Visa Medical and character.
3. Tickets and travel plan for 1 month or 3 months or 6 months and visit visa extension possible in NZ.

Comment: 4. Please explain detailed information shift JSV to RV. 
For example, my wife will go 1st September 2019 and she will get any job offer on 5th September 2019 and on 6th September 2019 she inform CO about Job Offer what will next step and how long officially takes to activate RV. This step is very confusing because 3 months time or 12 month time is mandatory after inform CO about a job offer and do the same or can switch another job in between.

Comment: @NZ Seeker I can’t answer that, you’d have to ask the NZ authorities. It seems very clearly explained in the guide I linked to. Also common sense says it’s unlikely any country would give a resident visa to someone without a job in the country they’re applying to. From what I’ve seen on this and other sites, it’s pretty common for families to be separated in the short-term eg while the main applicant finds work.  You seem to have misunderstood what Expatriates SE is - we’re just a collection of people with a degree of knowledge on the internet, not an official resource.

Comment: thanks for your reply and I appreciate you. I understand your reply In my opinion, your guide me and answer me for 1 question could you please put some light of your opinion for question 2, 3 and 4, please. sorry to bother you please guide me I am so upset.

Comment: @NZ Seeker Q2 The type of jobs you’re listing don’t look like ‘skilled employment’ to me. Q3 No-one can predict the chances of getting a visa. ‘Obviously borrow money’ - that’s often a very bad idea from a visa application point of view. Q4 As I understand the process, if your wife gets a suitable skilled job she would notify NZ Immigration and they will assess a residency application. Remember that recruitment can take time, depending on her prospective employer’s practices. She should perhaps try to get a job offer from her current location instead of moving to NZ on the basis of JS visa.

Comment: Thanks, @Traveller for your kind reply.    very good point you guide me to apply and try to get Job Offer in Home country, what I understand should my wife apply online if she gets Job Offer then she can inform CO and could process move forward. There is a question if CO working on it RV will activate from Home Country or Have to go on JSV Visa in NZ and start working there for at least 3 months. is it right?

Comment: @NZ Seeker I have to be honest and say I really think you need to do some more research/reading on the official NZ website to ensure you understand the process for both your wife (as the main applicant) and the rest of the family as dependents. You should also research cost of living data eg https://movetonewzealand.net/cost-of-living-in-new-zealand/ if you haven’t already. If you have further questions, please post them separately with a x-reference to this one.